# I am facing Dagger implementation issue

Tags: android, dagger-2, android-studio-3.0, dagger

> I implemented complete dagger implementation like added
>   component,provides,module and Inject and at the end i face following
>   issue kindly suggest solution

```
Program type already present: dagger.internal.codegen.DaggerStreams$$Lambda$12
```

> here is gradle code

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "app.rxjavaexample.com.daggerexample"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.16'
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.16'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'
    annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.16'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.0.2'
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> issue resolved after removing following link and add this in gradle file

```
implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.17'
```

Answer (score 5):

Remove this line:

```
implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.16'
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue occurs because of dependency conflicts Dagger 1 and Dagger 2 ,
have two options

1. Dagger 1 and Dagger 2 live together 
   [Try this](https://fernandocejas.com/2016/08/03/android-dagger-1-and-2-living-together/)

2.Migrate to Dagger 2
(Best solution because Dagger v1 is deprecated)

change your gradle dependencies to

```
implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android:2.17'
implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.17'
annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.17'
//default dependency
annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.17'
```

Answer (score -2):

```
 annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.15'
```

change version to 2.15 may be that will work
also change implementation to compile for dagger

Comment: compile is absolete from 23 version to onword